# Core plot disable y axes scaling, scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot, ipod

I want to make a thing like this: http://youtu.be/PeRhxSCx2xM

I try to implement this method:

```
//viewDidLoad
//plotSpace.delegate = self;

- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space
     willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange
             forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate {

    NSLog(@"WillChangePlotRangeTo");

    // only allows scrolling to the right
    // remove this to have scrolling in both directions
    if (newRange.locationDouble < 0.0F) {
        newRange.location = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0);
    }

    // Adjust axis to keep them in view at the left and bottom;
    // adjust scale-labels to match the scroll.
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateX) {
        axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = newRange.location;
        axisSet.xAxis.titleLocation = CPTDecimalFromFloat(newRange.locationDouble +
                                                         (newRange.lengthDouble / 2.0F));
    } else {
        axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = newRange.location;
        axisSet.yAxis.titleLocation = CPTDecimalFromFloat(newRange.locationDouble +
                                                         (newRange.lengthDouble / 2.0F));
    }

    return newRange;
}
```

And i try this to, this solution works when i zoom-out, but not work when i zoom in.

```
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(1.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(3.0)];
plotSpace.globalYRange = plotSpace.yRange;
```

anyone please explain me, what is the correct result, and how its work actually.

Thanks the replies

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is to just ignore the `newRange` and return the existing `yRange` for the y-coordinate. You don't need to bother with updating the axis properties here, either. There are easier ways to do that.

## Graph setup:

```
// leave the titleLocation for both axes at the default (NAN) to center the titles
xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```

## Plot space delegate:

```
- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space
      willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange
              forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate {

    CPTPlotRange *updatedRange = nil;

    switch ( coordinate ) {
    case CPTCoordinateX:
        if (newRange.locationDouble < 0.0F) {
            CPTMutablePlotRange *mutableRange = [[newRange mutableCopy] autorelease];
            mutableRange.location = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0);
            updatedRange = mutableRange;
        }
        else {
            updatedRange = newRange;
        }
        break;
    case CPTCoordinateY:
        updatedRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace *)space).yRange;
        break;
    }
    return updatedRange;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer it's working, thank you very very much, only 1 thing: when i make a big zoom out the application crash with this messages: -[CPTPlotRange mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd876030
2012-03-01 07:41:58.676 SSDev[823:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CPTPlotRange mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd876030'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar situation and the problem and it drove me crazy because I forgot to set delegate:

```
plotSpace.delegate = self;
```